# EF Reverse POCO with Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-6

Has anyone managed to get EF, Reverse POCO, and Oracle all in the sandbox at the same time?

Seems like judicious application of Nuget (EF and Oracle) would make all it takes. But not so.

Any ides?

Comment: It only works for SQL Server and SQL CE currently.

Answer (score 1):

The EF Reverse poco template only supports SQL Server